# My first android application. I tthink onCreate method or the whole class is just not getting called. What could be reason?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have created my first application for android "Hello android". With using Eclipse, ADT and android sdk. First time using all 3. I have below code.

```
package helloandroid.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           TextView tv = new TextView(this);
           tv.setText("Hello, Android");
           setContentView(tv);
       }
}
```

When i run this a blank mobile screen apperas (also 3-4 command prompts opens), that black screen after a while starts looking like typical android mobile screen. Mobile screen works fine but i do not see "Hello, Android" writen any where. What could be the reason. Even i am putting debuggers but control does not come there.

Comment: you can start with this simple tutorial 

http://developer-android.blogspot.in/2012/06/textview-in-android.html

Comment: I dunno, I created a new project and pasted your code in and it worked just fine.  Is that code the complete extent of it?  Since you said you are new to Eclipse, I'll mention that your breakpoint issue might be becasue you hit the run button instead of the debug button... The run button just runs the program, even if you've set breakpoints.  You need to use the debug button to have the breakpoints active.

Comment: I am first time to mobile development I was expecting output on home screen. Now I figured out. Menu --> Custom Code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I had to go on "Menu" in mobile screen then on "custon code" where i see my application.

Comment: I think you are verrrrrrrrry new to android :)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the tutorial [Android Hello World](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html)  properly and completely.

It looks like you have a problem at

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
```

or in your androidManifest.xml.

Follow the guide step by step.